# Can "open with" be made to open a selected set of files in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I notice that if I select several files and the right-click -> Open, all the files are opened in their respective applications. But if I use right-click -> Open With, only one file (apparently selected at random) is opened. (I'm trying to open various source files in Notepad.)

Is there any way a multiply-selected "Open With" can be persuaded to work?

Comment: it's seemingly not possible to open multiple files with the open with on the context menu. Have a look at this discussion: http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Vista-Context-menu-Open-multiple-files-ftopict377143.html. Although will look if someone else has found a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do what your asking, but I would suggest downloading [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  You can select multiple files and select Edit with Notepad++ from the context menu.  That will open all the files in a tabbed view.

Answer (score 1):

If you associate all the different file types you need to open with Notepad, the Open command should open all of them in Notepad.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I'd like to be able to do that, but the file extensions mean I can't (the file names are Something.bas, because they are VAX Basic files currently residing on my PC, and I don't want to affect the Visual Basic files SomethingElse.bas).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but do see it would be useful to have a right click selection "open all with" when you multiple select.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will work for you.

Create a .bat file in the directory where the files you want to open (for this example I assumed they were all .txt files to be opened with notepad.exe) and paste this:

```
@echo off

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
    start notepad.exe %%A
)
```

Save it as `multipleopen.bat` then just select all the .txt files you want and drag them to the `multipleopen.bat` you just created.